# curl --tlsv1.3, OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

Small question regarding a curl command on a TLSV1.3 endpoint, and the error "OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support".

The endpoint is a third party endpoint I have no control over, but from the spec, is TLSv1.3 enabled.

Hence, if I curl like this: It will yield the error, which is somehow expected.

```
./curl -vik https://third-party.com:18090/health
*   Trying x:18090...
* Connected to third-party.com (x) port 18090 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
* error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

But I also tried this: (note the --tlsv1.3, and it is returning this error.

```
curl --tlsv1.3 -vik https://third-party.com:18090/health
*   Trying x:18090...
* Connected to third-party.com (x) port 18090 (#0)
* OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support
* Closing connection 0
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support
```

**OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support**

The thing is, I haven't built openssl, I just did `yum -y install -y openssl openssl-devel`

May I ask how can I make my curl work with tlsv1.3, or how to fix this issue please?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wording "OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.3 support" may be misleading. It actually means this particular curl executable was built to use OpenSSL for SSL/TLS protocol (not one of several other options) AND the version/build of OpenSSL being used does not support TLS1.3; see function `set_ssl_version_min_max_legacy` in https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/openssl.c .
Looking at your error message it is clearly from an OpenSSL version below 1.1.0 (released in 2016), and it is definitely true such versions do not support TLS1.3. Only OpenSSL 1.1.1 (2018) now supports TLS1.3 (3.0.0, currently in alpha, also will) (2023 update: did).

You can't make that curl do TLS1.3. Since you are apparently using a RedHat-family system of some kind, depending on which system it is there may be other curl builds available either in a standard repository or an optional one. If not, you'll need to get OpenSSL 1.1.1 (or higher) which again may be available in a repository or else you'll have to build from source, and then build (sufficiently recent) curl from source to use that OpenSSL.

An alternative approach, instead of getting this to work directly on your system, is to use another system: either a real system, possibly in the cloud; or a virtual machine on your system; or a docker or similar container which basically virtualizes only the OS but not the underlying hardware.

Comment: That link is not a permalink so it points at the wrong line now that openssl.c was modified in the repository since the link was created.

Answer (score 6):

On macOS, I succeed by installing a new curl version by `brew install curl`.

Then you can run something, for example

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl --version
```

or

```
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl --tlsv1.3 --request GET \
     --url https://localhost:9200 \
     --cacert ca.crt \
     --key tls.key \
     --cert tls.crt \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --verbose
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I downvoted this answer, because the question is not about MacOS but about a RHEL compatible system (with yum).
This answer may be very useful to some people, but I don't think it should be on top. The answer from @dave_thompson_085 should.

Comment: I'm not sorry. I upvoted this answer, because this answered my question. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `curl` directly after `brew install curl`  under macOS. You need to have `curl` in your `PATH` through

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/YOURNAME/.bash_profile`

So we could use `curl` directly like

`curl --tlsv1.3  xxxxx`

---

One more thing, another piece of advice put in your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`):

`export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1`

However, it **failed** to use the latest `curl` installed by `brew`.